# Method taking in 2 arguments (array of ints, and a single int)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

I've created a method, that, given a array of numbers and an integer n, it calculates the longest occurrence of the integer n. For example `1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1`, given the number 1, the longest sequence is 4. I'm just using 0's and 1's at the moment to keep it simple, however I'm really stuck on implementing my main method to test this function - I'm not sure how to separate the integer "n" and the array of ints when reading from the command line, and I'm hoping I could be given some pointers/help. Here's my code:

```
public class OneB {

public static int longestSeq(int[] nums, int n) {


    int max = 0;
    int curLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (i == n) {
            curLength++;
            if (curLength > max)
                max = curLength;
        } else
            curLength = 0;
    }
    return max;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {  

    int[] nums = new int[args.length-2];
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[args.length-1]);

    for (int i = 0; args.length-1 > i; i++) {
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }


    int result = longestSeq(nums, n);
    System.out.println(result);


      }
}
```

What I'm aiming is for the last number in the command line to be used as the integer n, whilst everything before that will be used as the array nums.

With the input `1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1` (the last 1 being my "n" value - 4 being the expected output") I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at OneB.main(OneB.java:26)
```

Comment: Then why do you create the array 2 elements smaller than the arg list?

Comment: If I were to input 1 0 0 0 1 on the command line, args.length would be 5, and index 4 would be my n value, and the array would stop at index 3, hence the (args.length-2) - however I'm not entirely sure I'm thinking about it the right way.

Comment: You're right, you're not thinking about it the right way.

Comment: Would you be able to give me some pointers?

Comment: Think about it!  If your command line is 5 items long, 4 of those need to go into your array.  So your array needs to be 4 elements long.  An array of 4 elements would be addressed 0..3.

Comment: (With regard to all this it's generally NOT a good idea to try to use some memorized "formula" that x should be y-1 or whatever, but rather work out the array dimensions and `for` loop index start/end values from "first principles".)

Comment: Got it working - gave it some thought, I need to stop programming at midnight, does me no good, thanks for your help dude.

Answer (score 0):

Check the JavaDoc for ArrayOutOfBounds.
Then put a break point in your code (you already have the information needed to figure out which line) and step through your code slowly, watching the values of *all* your variables.